# Can we have some click through stats for Community Bulletin?

Tags: support, community-bulletin

We have a section called "Community Bulletin" on the [landing page of Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) which contains links to events (like Moderator elections), [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) meta posts, recently held meta discussions along with some old meta discussions once a while.

[image: Communty Bulletin on AU homepage]

Can we have some statistics about the click through rates of those links? Does it actually help to have a meta post featured in the Bulletin? Any other insight which might be available about them is also welcome.